# Filter address url

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have this example string list:

```
var s="http://www.website1.com/, http://www.website2.es/forum/something, http://website3.info, website4.is";
```

and the output would be:

```
website1.com

website2.es

website3.info

website.is
```

How can I achieve this with **minimum fuzz** in jquery *or* javascript?

Comment: Do you need an array to work with ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not the most efficient, but using parse_url from php.js (http://phpjs.org/functions/parse_url/):

```
var sList = "http://www.website1.com/, http://www.website2.es/forum/something, http://website3.info, website4.is";

var aStr = sList.split(', ');

var sResult = "";

for(var i in aStr) 
{
  var oUrlParts = parse_url(aStr[i]);
  sResult += oUrlParts['host']+"\n\n";
}

console.log(sResult);
```

Comment: Did you test this? It gives `undefined` for the fourth value, "website4.is," and it keeps the "www" subdomains on the first two values. http://jsfiddle.net/KUGbN/

Comment: Confirmed. Seems to need a leading `protocol://` in the string, otherwise it gives `undefined`. http://jsfiddle.net/KUGbN/2/

Answer (score 2):

Why not simply this:

```
//your string:
var str=("http://www.website1.com/, http://www.website2.es/forum/something, http://website3.info, website4.is");

//my function:
function gtBaseUrl(s){ 
    return s.split('://').pop().split('/')[0]; 
}

//example use:
var lnks=str.split(', ');

for(var i=0, L=lnks.length; i < L; i++){
    //do stuff with each url
    alert( gtBaseUrl(lnks[i]).replace(/^www./i,'') );
    //if you don't want www. stripped then remove: ' .replace(/^www./i,'') '
}
```

Working jsfiddle demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/wcCyw/4/).

You can modify the for-loop it to whatever (formatted output) you need (using `innerHTML` and `br` *or* `\n` for in textarea, etc.)

Comment: You're explicitly stripping off "www" subdomains, but what about any other subdomain (*foo*.bar.com)? Subdomains should probably be either included or excluded across the board, not selectively like this.

Comment: @DaggNabbit: I know, but then what about `foo.co.uk` versus `www.foo.co.uk` ?  Indeed it might be better (for other readers) to leave out the `.replace(/^www./i,'')` but then it wouldn't conform to the askers question where www is stripped.

Comment: Yep, that's the problem with trying to remove subdomains, you need to check it against a list of actual TLDs, and it's a looong list... really your answer is the only one here that actually does what the OP requested (given his sample data, at least). I only left my answer because it gives the same results as the accepted answer, but with way less code.

Comment: Couldn't one shorten that list so it only contains cases like `.co.uk`?    I noticed the anchors `hostname` property (from your answer) seems to return everything before the first `/` after removing the `protocol://` (so then it seems that `s.split('://').pop().split('/')[0]` would give the same result).    As a side-note (to these interesting comments): my understanding is that the current 'convention' is that `www` is usually an alias for the root (ie `foo.com`), but in strict scenarios you are absolutely right!

Comment: Sometimes I think it's even more complicated than that. Consider for example the Florida Department of Corrections: `www.dc.state.fl.us` ... what to do with that?

Answer (score 1):

The usual way to do this in JavaScript is create an `a` element, assign the URL to its `href` property, and then get its `hostname` property.

```
var a = document.createElement('a');
a.href = "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16429929/filter-address-url";
console.log(a.hostname); // "stackoverflow.com"
```

No external dependencies, three lines of code.

---

Of course, you could also do something like:

```
"http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16429929/filter-address-url".split('/')[2]
```

---

From your question, it looks like you don't want subdomains ("www") in the results, but since you accepted an answer that returns subdomains (and fails on the fourth value), I'll leave this here.

Comment: +1 for the correct way. But `"http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16429929/filter-address-url".split('/')[2]` will not work given the askers examples (where urls are without http://).  PS, what do you think about my answer? Can you think of a valid url where my function would fail?

Comment: @GitaarLAB, good point (the accepted answer fails there too, though, and really it's not a proper URL, so the "real" solution, whatever it is, probably "should" fail there) :) Just left a comment on your answer...